# nested shape validation javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
import get from "lodash.get";

const x = [
  {
    value: 1
  },
  {
    value: {
      min: undefined,
      max: 2
    }
  }
];

console.log(
  "valid: ",
  x.every(o => o.value || (get(o, "value.min") && get(o, "value.max")))
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-dijkstra-g42yy

I expect the valid to be false but it returned true although the value.min is undefined. What is the problem here?

Comment: You should try making your question a little more clear with exactly what "validation" means in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your first condition (`o.value`) returns true for the second item--since `value` is an object and therefore not falsy--so your check for min/max never runs.

```js
const x = [
  {
    value: 1
  },
  {
    value: {
      min: undefined,
      max: 2
    }
  }
];

// utility to check for null/undefined
const c = v => v != null;

console.log(x.every(({ value }) => (
  typeof value === 'object'
? c(value.min) && c(value.max)
: c(value)
)));
```

Comment: what if the value can also accept string? typeof o.value === 'string'?

Comment: You could reverse the order and check for 'object' for the min/max test, then check the primitive.